# How do I fix the #ERROR in Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I have a problem when I try use this condition in Report Builder:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TIPO.Value="CREDITO", Fields!VENTA.Value, 0))
```

When there's no data in the dataset that satisfies the negative condition the returned value is the sum of the values that meet the condition. However, when there are mixed values (some meet the condition. some don't) I get the #ERROR.

I've tried:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TIPO.Value="CREDITO", 1, 0))
```

Basically, it's like counting the values that meet the condition.

How do I get it to work in all cases, with/without values that meet the condition?

Comment: Please translate your question to English

Comment: `=Sum(IIf(Fields!TIPO.Value="CREDITO", Fields!VENTA.Value, 0))` is not "SQL" to begin with. So the tag `sql` seems also incorrect

Comment: minor rewording

Comment: What's the error that you get when there are mixed values?